# antlr recognized wrong parser

Tags: parsing, antlr

I was using antlr 3.4 to write a parser grammar, like this:

```
var : VAR_LEFT_PART  atom_var VAR_RIGHT_PART ;
atom_var : ID |   VAR_LEFT_PART ID VAR_RIGHT_PART ;

VAR_LEFT_PART : '{{';
VAR_RIGHT_PART : '}}';
ID : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '_')* ;
INT :   ('1'..'9')('0'..'9')* ;
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ;
WS  :   (' '|'\t')+ { $channel = HIDDEN;} ;
```

when I test a case below:

[image]

the problem is that I the string "{{ {test} }}" is not right, but the parser recognized the ID a wrong token, what's the problem?

Comment: You should check if there is any exception during parsing. ANTLR usually attempts to recover from parsing errors/exceptions, and then the tree can be malformed like what you observed.

Comment: Thanks, Lex, I think It's a ANTLR's error recovery, '{' is not a valid token at all.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with ANTLR 3.4, it seems to work properly. The interpreter of the eclipse plugin drew the same wrong tree as in your post, but it's known to be buggy.

Comment: thanks Andy, if it's just a bug, I will continue to add some grammar and to write a test case by hand.